# Split string and display below other column data using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I am using SQL Server 2014.

I am having following table data.

```
SRNO    ITEM      DESCRIPTION
----------------------------------------
1       SHOES     BLACK,SPORTS,ADIDAS
2       PEN       RED,STATIONARY,WILLIAM
```

I want the result as below

```
SRNO    ITEM                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       SHOES
            BLACK
            SPORTS
            ADIDAS

2       PEN
            RED
            STATIONARY
            WILLIAM
```

Comment: How do I show null values in SRNO for description?

Comment: I think this question is not duplicate as you marked it.